# How to get the integer part of a string in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

My string has the format of A3, A5, A38... and I'm only interested in the integer part of it.

I want something like:

```
let getIntofString s = match s with
"A1" -> 1
| ..
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `string_of_int` from the initially opened module and at `sub` from the standard library's `String` module. That should get you started.

Comment: Yeah, sub is probably what I need. I don't know the length of the string (since it may have 1 number, or even 3, like A5 and A157) but together with length I'll pull it of. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Scanf module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html) allows for some simple pattern matching where no elaborate parsing is needed.

Example:

```
let identity x = x
let parseAInt s =
  Scanf.sscanf s "A%u" identity
```

Here, `Scanf.sscanf` takes as its first argument the input string, as its second argument the pattern to be matched (`%u` denoting an unsigned integer), and as its third argument a function that converts the parsed results into the type needed. As we don't need such a conversion in this case, the identity function suffices here.

Note that you may have to handle exceptions (`Scanf.Scan_failure` for a pattern mismatch, `End_of_file` for running out of characters to read, or `Failure` for being unable to convert a string to a number) if you cannot guarantee that the input to this function actually matches the pattern (for example, because it was supplied by a user).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sub, length and **int_of_string**.

```
open String

let getIntofString s =
  let l=length s in
  let si=sub s 1 (l-1) in
  int_of_string si
;;
```

Test

> ```
> # getIntofString "A18";;
> - : int = 18
>
> # getIntofString "A";;
> Exception: Failure "int_of_string".
>
> # getIntofString "";;
> Exception: Invalid_argument "String.sub / Bytes.sub".
> ```